# How can I synchronize two audio files?

Tags: audio, sync, ffmpeg

I've got many audio files of the same scene, but recorded with different devices.
I would like to automaticaly synchronize the sources.

I searched the web for a solution an I understood that I should compare two signals (with a cross-correlation), add a small delay to one signal, and re-compare the two signal until I have the less difference between them.

My problem is more with the implementation. Wich tool can do that ? I work with ffmpeg and I've seen that there is FFT tools included but with no documentation. How can I compare two signals ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is automatic solution an only option, or can you also do it by hand, if it may be quicker this time)?

Comment: Automatic only. I've got a lot of signals. I know that by hand, I can do that visualy with audacity or an other software.

Comment: plural eyes is supposed to perform that function in software, but having re-synced manually myself I doubt it can do as well as a human.  I have seen audios that would be a challenge for any software, just because of differences in recording type (auto volume on 1 source) distance from the sound and other sounds, echo and delay from distance adding to the fun. Why are even the worst film makers always found with a clapboard, because of what your going through now :-)